# "Error: Invalid Number." when sending an SMS

Tags: sms, 5.0-lollipop, moto-x

I have the 2014 Moto X, running Lollipop. For some contacts, when I try to send them a message, I get an SMS saying "Error: Invalid Number."

I have noticed that this happens when I go to compose a message in the stock Messages app and then search for a contact. For example, if I start typing "Ka" in the search box,it will suggest all contacts with "Ka" in the name. Then I tap the one I want to send a message to, and for some reason, the number gets truncated. If the contact has the number +1 (123) 456-7890, then after I tap it, it shows up as +1 456-7890 and hence is unable to deliver the message since it is an invalid number.

This also only happens with some contacts, seemingly at random, since all my numbers are formatted the same way, so it can't be because of the format.

Has anyone else experienced this and what can be done to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I have the Moto X as well, same issue (kept showing 7 digit number instead of 10). Read somewhere to delete the entire conversation (all text messages to/from that contact) and after that when I went to compose a new message, the contact showed up as 10 digits and the text went through.

I hope this works for you!